# Bus seat arrangment javascript algorithm

Tags: javascript, css

I am new to programming,

I want to implement a bus seating arrangement using javascript.

my function :

```js
var init = function (reservedSeat) {
            var str = [], seatNo, className;
            bus_capacity = settings.cols * settings.rows;
            for (i = 0; i < settings.cols; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < settings.rows; j++) {
                   
                    seatNo = (i + j * settings.cols + 1);
                    className = settings.seatCss + ' ' + settings.rowCssPrefix + i.toString() + ' ' + settings.colCssPrefix + j.toString();
                    if (seatNo > (bus_capacity + settings.offset) ) {break};
                  
                    if ( $.isArray(reservedSeat) && $.inArray(seatNo, reservedSeat) != -1) {
                        className += ' ' + settings.selectedSeatCss;
                    }
                    str.push('<li data-toggle="modal" href="#sell_ticket" class="' + className + '"' +
                              'style="top:' + (i * settings.seatHeight).toString() + 'px;left:' + (j * settings.seatWidth).toString() + 'px">' +
                              '<h4><a  title="' + seatNo + '">' + seatNo + '</a></h3>' +
                              '</li>');
                }
            }

            $('#place').html(str.join(''));
        };
```

That's a function which displays seats with specified seat numbers, however I would  like to be displaying ... this :

> [1]  [2]      [5] [4] [3]
>
> [6]  [7]    [10] [9] [8]
>
> ....
>
> ....

Comment: Welcome to SO. You would benefit from having a look around [help]. Especially [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: so .. what have you done so far (besides searching)?

Comment: Is it just me or does "bus seat arrangement algorithm" sound like a serious scientific name for a search algorithm? :D

Comment: certain buses have a way in which their seats are numbered on board, so that's what i was referring to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getSeatPos(seat) {
    seat--;
    return {
        row: Math.floor(seat / 5) + 1,
        place: [1, 2, 5, 4, 3][seat % 5]
    };
}
var i;
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    document.write(i + ': ' + JSON.stringify(getSeatPos(i), null, 4) + '<br>');
}
```

the calculation is base on 1..n, but we need 0..(n-1). the rest is in the immediate called array.

or arrange the IDs in desired position

Comment: thank you very much - nina scholz

Comment: And with that correct answer with full working code.. Not a shred was learned. ;'] And the OP would not be seen again until next weeks homework assignment was issued.